# How to find hot and cold pixels of Temperature for SEBAL in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to find Hot and Cold pixels for SEBAL model. I created a yearly temperature from Landsat 8 collection. But I am struggling to find min and max values.

```
var image = filtered.first();
print(image);
print('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_10',image.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_10'));
print('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_10',image.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_10'));
print('K1_CONSTANT_BAND_10',image.get('K1_CONSTANT_BAND_10'));
print('K2_CONSTANT_BAND_10',image.get('K2_CONSTANT_BAND_10'));

function addLST(image) {
  var Rc = image.expression(
    'L*0.0003342 + 0.1', 
    {'L': image.select('B10')});
  
  var t1 = image.expression(
    '(1321.0789 / log (774.8853 * Enb / Rc + 1))',
    {'Enb':image.select('Enb'),'Rc': Rc}).rename('Temperature');

  return image.addBands(t1);
  
}

var filtered=filtered.map(addLST); 
var meanF = filtered.mean();
var meanT = meanF.select('Temperature');
```

I tried to use min() and reducer.min() and reducer.max() functions, but it did not work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am going to answer this question by using a code of one of your former question where I used brightness temperature instead. You should adapt it for your LST temperatures.

First of all, I need an Image Collection and a geometry for Min Max reducers. So, I filtered for an arbitrary dates range and geometry in following code to do that. Result will be a paired list for min max values in geometry area for each image in filtered Image Collection.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1')
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry))
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01');

print(dataset);

var image = dataset.first();

print(image);

print('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_10',image.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_10'));
print('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_10',image.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_10'));
print('K1_CONSTANT_BAND_10',image.get('K1_CONSTANT_BAND_10'));
print('K2_CONSTANT_BAND_10',image.get('K2_CONSTANT_BAND_10'));

Map.centerObject(image);
//Map.addLayer(image);
Map.addLayer(geometry);

function addLST(image) {
  var Rc = image.expression(
    'L*0.0003342 + 0.1', 
    {'L': image.select('B10')});

  var t1 = image.expression(
    '(1321.0789 / log (774.8853 / Rc + 1)) - 273.15',
    {'Rc': Rc}).rename('Temperature');

  return image.addBands(t1);
  
}

var parVis = {"opacity":1,
                 "bands":["Temperature"],
                 "min":1.7644088414766657,
                 "max":21.559778405375994,
                 "palette":['blue','pink','brown','orange','yellow','green']};

var filtered = dataset.map(addLST); 

print(filtered);

//Map.addLayer(filtered.first().select('Temperature'), parVis, 'Temperature');

var filtered_list = filtered.toList(filtered.size());

var reducers = ee.Reducer.min().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.max(),
  sharedInputs: true
  });

var pairedMinMax = filtered_list.map(function (ele) {
  
  var value = ee.Image(ele)
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer:reducers, 
      geometry:geometry,
      bestEffort:true});
    
  return [value.get('Temperature_min'), value.get('Temperature_max')];
  
});

print(pairedMinMax);
```

After running [above code](https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/75190313b88a2595cd5ac9a56168dd1e) in GEE code editor, I got result of following picture for min, max paired list (inside red rectangle). You should adapt it for your particular use.

[image]

Comment: Sir, do you do online mentoring or consultation for money?